# Two IF statments in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to set up an `IF` statement on a spreadsheet, so that I can estimate my monthly pay, however, I am having trouble with the `IF` statement.

This statement is in `L2`:

```
=IF(D2="Sun", 10.78, 6.47, OR(D2="Sat", 8.62))
```

what I am trying to say is that when:

> if D2 = "sun" then £10.78 else £6.47 yet If D2 = Sat £8.62

Ok, I have got it working with:

```
=IF(D2="Sun", 10.78, IF(D2="Sat", 8.62, IF(D2="Mon", 6.47, IF(D2="Tue", 6.47,
  IF(D2="Wed", 6.47, IF(D2="Thu", 6.47, IF(D2="Fri", 6.47)))))))
```

I was wondering however, is there a way to condense it with an else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=if(D2="Sat",8.62,if(D2="Sun",10.78,6.47))
```

How it works:-

The first statement says if D2 is a Saturday then 8.62, if its a Sunday then 10.78, else if there is any other thing then 6.47....